# C++ Linked list creation - passing in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, linked-list

I am working on creating a linked list in c++, and I can't figure out how to pass an array as an argument in the constructor, or if thats even legal syntax.

This is the error I get:

```
CheckTextFile.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node(char*, int)’:
CheckTextFile.cpp:19: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [0u]’
CheckTextFile.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node(char*, int, Node*)’:
CheckTextFile.cpp:24: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [0u]’
```

Here is my code:

```
class Node{
public:
    int length;
    char data[];
    Node * next;
    Node(char x[], int y){
        data = x;
        length = y;
        next = NULL;
    }
    Node(char x[], int y, Node * z){
        data = x;
        length = y;
        next = z;
    }
```

};

Comment: "I am working on creating a linked list in c++", purely as an academic exercise, one hopes. The world doesn't need another C++ list class!

Answer (score 3):

Your argument passing is fine. However, your:

```
char data[];
```

declares an array with no size, so it's not surprising that the compiler refuses to generate code to put anything in there. Perhaps try:

```
std::string data;
```

This is assuming that your `x[]` represents a NUL-terminated C string.

After you do that, learn about the *member initialisation syntax* for constructors.

Comment: That's not what the compiler is choking on(I am fairly sure the zero size array is a gcc extension). The compiler is failing on the assignement of the arrays(you can't copy arrays like that in C++).

Comment: The error is about assignment inside the constructor not due to passing of pointer to array.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an pointer to the first element of the array, and actually that is correct.

The compiler is complaining about assignment inside the constructor:

```
data = x;
```

You cannot assign arrays as such, not like objects, you will have to copy each element from the source array to the target array.
Either using a looping construct or using `std::copy`.

A trivial way(efficient would be to use `std::copy`) of doing so:

```
Node(char x[], int y)
{
     for(int i = 0;i<y; ++i)
     { 
         data[i] = x[i];
     }
     length = y;
     next = 0;
}
```

Or Simply

```
std::copy(x,x+y,data);
```

And it will **[compile cleanly](http://ideone.com/FBlBV)**.

On a side note, you are much better off using `std::string` rather than using char arrays.

Comment: memcpy would probably be the most "C-like" way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in C++, you can't have an array of unspecified size. Also, you can use a pointer instead of an array or `std:string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node{
public:
    int length;
    char *ptr_data;  //pointer 
    Node * next;
    Node(char *x, int y){
        ptr_data = x;  //pointer assignment
        length = y;
        next = NULL;
    }
    Node(char *x, int y, Node * z){
        ptr_data = x;    //pointer assignment
        length = y;
        next = z;
    }
};
```

Comment: this will be more efficient as it avoids unnecessary copies. only problem arises if char *x goes out of scope. if such situation exists then you should use copy. and this being char array strcpy(dest,source) will do.